# How I can make a prediction in data mining?

Tags: weka

I have an Excel file containing the following data.

> [image: screenshot]

I want to apply it on Weka by k-nearest neighbor classifier.

How I can make a prediction of the new instance?
How can I set the parameters of this instance to obtain prediction about it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have enough data to work with here. Your model will be wildly inaccurate. If you are starting with machine learning, I would recommend the Iris data set to start with. I started with machine learning [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/).

If you want to start with Weka, I would use a dataset from researchers, like the MNIST database of handwritten digits which can be found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data), and a guide for it in python [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-networks-python-keras/). On the same site, there is a tutorial for the Weka gui, if you look hard enough.